# Is there any way to change the orientation of the layout shown in the second screen when using cwac-presentation library?

Tags: android, orientation, commonsware-cwac

I have an app that uses the cwac-presentation library. When starting the service and displaying the layout on the second display, I want it to be landscape oriented but keep the layout on my device on portrait, but I cannot find a way to these different orientations. If I request an orientation change, it happens on both screens (as expected). Has anyone found a solution to this issue?

Comment: "I have an app that uses the cwac-presentation library" -- could you be more specific? What exactly are you using from the library?

Comment: I only use the PresentationService and the PresentationHelper in order to start a presentation on another display, while being able to continue using the features of the app on the device.

Comment: An orientation change should not affect a service. That being said, I'm having difficulties running any of my demos on a Nexus 10 running 5.0.2, so I have some work to do...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, at least not on a Hudl 2. On the Hudl 2, default screen mirroring mimics the device orientation, so a portrait device has a portrait mirror on the monitor/projector. However, the `demoService` project correctly leaves everything alone, as it is not affected by the configuration change, and so even though the foreground switches between portrait and landscape, the content of the external monitor does not.